# linux - How do I capture all of my compiler's output to a file as well as need to display output

Tags: c, linux, shell

The below program redirects all my output to log file. I need to display all the output along with log file. How can this be achieved?

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out > log.txt
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`tee`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html):

```
$ ./a.out | tee log.txt
```

Comment: You might want to use `./a.out 2>&1 | tee log.txt` to make you you get both `stdout` and `stderr` messages (depending on what you want in the log).

Comment: whether ./a.out | tee log.txt does not add stderr and stdout ?

Comment: if i want to send mail if any error occurred  by echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" someone@somewhere.com method. But i want to detect the error message how should i detect the error message in script ?